Conditions under which a non-doubly connected graph $G$ becomes doubly connected when a suitable edge is added?
What are the conditions under which a non-doubly connected graph $G$ becomes doubly connected when a suitable edge is added?
I thought about this problem and was able to set some conditions for this graph: $G$ is connected, consists of no more than 3 blocks and, accordingly, no more than 2 points of articulation. At the same time, there should also be no more than 2 hanging vertices and a maximum of 2 blocks are connected through each point.
But I do not know if these conditions are sufficient to describe all such graphs.
Any help with this problem?

Such a $G$ can have an arbitrary large number of blocks. Take for instance a path graph: all 'inner' vertices are cut-vertices, and the graph becomes biconnected once the two 'outer' (i.e., degree 1) vertices are connected by an edge. And a generalization thereof: any graph whose block-cut tree graph is a path graph.
In fact, say a graph $G$ has 'property $P$' if it is non-biconnected but becomes biconnected by adding a suitable edge. Then note that $G$ has property $P$ if and only if the block-cut tree $BCT(G)$ of $G$ has property $P$. But a tree graph has property $P$ if and only if it is a path graph.
Conclusion: $G$ has property $P$ if and only if $BCT(G)$ is a path graph.
